# Location of an extended partiton in a physical disk?

Tags: windows, vhd

I am trying to copy a physical disk to a VHD file. It works fine when OS is on primary partition but when I try to copy OS which is on extended partition the VHD wont boot. The scenario is Boot files are on a primary partition and Windows system files on logical drive of an extended partition. In diskmgmt.msc it shows me the logical drive as first partition.

I have MBR and Extended bot record as well.

How can I know the where the actual extended partition and logical drives offsets are.

Comment: I don't know about Windows, but you could boot on your favourite Linux LiveCD and run `fdisk -l`. BTW not sure why this is tagged C++.

Comment: Why use Logical partition at all?
As far as I know it's just an alternative to primary partitions (which are limited to 4 per disk).